# How to import AppDelegate.h file in Pod project ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, cocoapods

I am new to the POD project.
I want to update the pod project viewControllers,for that I need to access the AppDelegate class in Pod Project.

I have tried to update the Pod configuration file to access the AppDelegate but not able to get success.

Comment: Why you wants it? It is not ideal stuff that you should do.

Comment: Instead of using your project classes into pod project use pod classes into your project. Make pod class instance and update anything from `AppDelegate` class. Also explain more about your requirement I think there might be a better and easy way to accomplish your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but I want to access my `AppDelegate` array object in to pod project classes,means when we access any pod class will update using `AppDelegate` array object.

Comment: I have one more option to create property in Pod class and set it from my project class. But problem is that the class which I want to update this class get access from pod project view controller.

POD(Structure)

1.WebViewClass - All the property set into it(Custom)
2.Main ViewController -which is controlling that WebViewClass
3.GridViewClass -which I want to update (This class will help you to open recent URL(Tab))

GridViewClass will load using `AppDelegate` array means this array will be updated using user requested url.

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to create a circular dependency between your app and the pod. The recommended way to do this would be to define a protocol in the pod and make your AppDelegate implement that protocol.

```
@protocol PodArrayProvider
    - (NSArray *)arrayToAccess:
@end

// in AppDelegate.m
#import <Pod/Pod.h>

@extension AppDelegate () <PodArrayProvider>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (NSArray *)arrayToAccess
{
    return self.realArray;
}
@end

// then in your pod, you can do:
id<PodArrayProvider> arrayProvider = (id<PodArrayProvider>)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSAssert([arrayProvider conformsTo:@protocol(PodArrayProvider)], @"bad app delegate!");
NSArray *things = [arrayProvider arrayToAccess];
```

Something like the structure above should work, but I would urge you to rethink this architecture. The pod is a dependency of the app and shouldn't know anything about the app. The app should be telling the pod everything it needs to know.